# can't run laravel 5.7 on php8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

hi guys I need help for this case
I can't run laravel 5.7 on php8, when I do "php artisan serve"
I got error:

```
thrown in /var/www/html/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 838
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in /var/www/html/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:838
```

I have tried to update composer required php version form `"^7.1.3"` to `"php": "^7.1.3|^8.0",`
and when I run `composer update` I got another error.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework[v5.7.0, ..., 5.7.x-dev] require php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework 5.7.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.7.0, ..., 5.7.x-dev].
```

I hope any body sharing what is solution for this case

Answer (score 2):

Both errors are related.

According to [The Official Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation) Laravel 5.7 only supports PHP >= 7.1.3.

Trying to force it to run on PHP8 will cause some funky things as PHP8 has a lot of game changing fixes/migrations/deprecation. All of which can be found [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.php).

If you want to use PHP8, use Laravel 8. If you want to use Laravel 5.7, use PHP7.

If you *must* use PHP8 and Laravel 5.7, I suggest you change the composer requiremnet to `"php": "^8.0",` but be prepared to troubleshoot a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 5.7 is not compatible with PHP 8. If you want to get PHP 8 support, make sure you're at the latest version of Laravel 6, 7, or 8.

There are also a couple of commonly used dependencies you'll need to update in your `composer.json` file:

- PHP to `php:^8.0`
- Faker to `fakerphp/faker:^1.9.1`
- PHPUnit to `phpunit/phpunit:^9.3`

Comment: Ok, I will try to upgrade my laravel project

Answer (score 1):

You can putting `exit($e);` in `App\Exceptions\Handler::report()` to give a better error message.

Answer (score 0):

delete vendors file
then run the command composer install