# I am trying to run a laravel application but i am getting this error

Tags: php, laravel, frontend, backend, web-development-server

My composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3||^8.0",
        "brian2694/laravel-toastr": "^5.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "ext-gd": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "kylekatarnls/update-helper": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

I am getting an error

> Problem 1
> - laravel/framework[v5.6.0, ..., 5.6.x-dev] require php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.2.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework 5.6.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.6.0, ..., 5.6.x-dev].

What should I do

I am trying to run it on localhost

Comment: which version  laravel you are using  ?

Comment: Is this an existing laravel application? Did you run this in xampp or wamp? If both are yes then you may had installed the latest xampp version which uses PHP 8.2. Download an older version of xampp or wamp that uses PHP 7.1

Comment: So as per the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6) for laravel 5.6, it says you can have a higher version of PHP `PHP >= 7.1.3` above 7.1.3. But it seems like your localhost is on 8.2.4 and your `composer.json` being `"php": "^7.3||^8.0",`, can you try it like this, change it to `"php": "^7.3||^8.2.4"`, run `composer update`?

Comment: You should also try install using ```composer install --ignore-platform-reqs``` or ```composer update --ignore-platform-reqs``` without changing anything or upgrading something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Composer sees wrong PHP Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46785969/laravel-composer-sees-wrong-php-version)

Comment: @Adi ignore the php version with `composer update --ignore-platform-reqs` is not a well applicable way

Comment: @LF00 did you see the marked answer? Also please check my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

To make it clear, you've to know why the error shows here.

1. Your composer.json file require `"php": "^7.3||^8.0",`, which you php 8.2.4 version matches. Refer to [composer versions and constraints](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md)
2. According to the [laravel 5.6 server requirement](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6#server-requirements), it requires `PHP >= 7.1.3`, which your php version 8.2.4 matches.
3. But from the actually latest [laravel 5.6.* composer package](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/framework#v5.6.40) use the `php: ^7.1.3`, which you php 8.2.4 not matches, So it show the error:

> laravel/framework[v5.6.0, ..., 5.6.x-dev] require php ^7.1.3 -> your
> php version (8.2.4) does not satisfy that requirement.

How to fix this, install the required php version, or use the laravel version to match you php version.

Comment: quick question, so i had commented changing composer to `"php": "^7.3||^8.2.4"` and then running `composer update`, this should work too right? I understand that `^8.0` allows versions like 8.0.1, 8.1.0, or 8.2.3 and so on, but if either isn't backward compatible then it would stop right? I am just clarifying for my knowledge

Comment: @Adi no, the error is triggered by the laravel 5.6 package's requirement `php ^7.1.3` which not include the php8. So modify the composer.json not works here. You need to install php7 for the laravel5.6, or use laravel version that use php8, or as you refered use the `--ignore-platform-reqs` parameters.

Comment: Oh i see, then this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67378625/cant-run-laravel-5-7-on-php8 or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69321058/laravel-5-8-running-on-php-8-0 answers it, right?

Answer (score -1):

It seems your php version is not compatible with your laravel version
your laravel version:5.4
your php version :8.2

you need php version 7 or upgrade your laravel
you can install older xampp with 7 php version

Comment: where are you getting this info from laravel version:5.4?

Comment: "laravel/framework": "5.6.*
in this version you must use php 7.*